# css styling for Flex PopUpButton

Tags: apache-flex, coding-style, popupmenu

How can I give a specific color (Let's say red) to the border of dropdown menu of Flex PopUpButton.
Also if how can I set text properties (text should be bold) of dropdown Menu of PopUpButton.

Thanks in advance 
- Atul

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

[Flex3 Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#)

On the left select Buttons and select PopUpButton and you will be able to see the styles you can change for this control...

For example,

change border color with: `borderColor: #ff0000;`

there color with: `themeColor: #ff0000;`

etc...
Ladislav